# how to work with custom select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

hi is there any idea of how to get the value from this fancy select box which change the select box into ul li on site load here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tovic/ZTHkQ/) for styled select box..

HTML

```
<select id="selectbox1">
    <option value="">Select an option&hellip;</option>     
</select>
```

JQuery

```
  $('select').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        numberOfOptions = $(this).children('option').length;
    $this.addClass('s-hidden');
    $this.wrap('<div class="select"></div>');
    $this.after('<div class="styledSelect"></div>');
    var $styledSelect = $this.next('div.styledSelect');
    $styledSelect.text($this.children('option').eq(0).text());
    var $list = $('<ul />', {
        'class': 'options'
    }).insertAfter($styledSelect);    
    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfOptions; i++) {
        $('<li />', {
            text: $this.children('option').eq(i).text(),
            rel: $this.children('option').eq(i).val()
        }).appendTo($list);
    }
    var $listItems = $list.children('li');   
    $styledSelect.click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $('div.styledSelect.active').each(function() {
            $(this).removeClass('active').next('ul.options').hide();
        });
        $(this).toggleClass('active').next('ul.options').toggle();
    });
    $listItems.click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $styledSelect.text($(this).text()).removeClass('active');
        $this.val($(this).attr('rel'));
        $list.hide();
        /* alert($this.val()); Uncomment this for demonstration! */
    });

    $(document).click(function() {
        $styledSelect.removeClass('active');
        $list.hide();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

> how to get the value from this fancy select box

You can get the selected value like this on click of `$listItems` :-

```
$listItems.click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $styledSelect.text($(this).text()).removeClass('active');
    $this.val($(this).attr('rel'));
    $list.hide();

    // Get the selected value here
    alert($styledSelect.text());
});
```

Demo : [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZTHkQ/691/)

Answer (score 0):

The styled select sets the value of the original select, because of this line:

```
        $this.val($(this).attr('rel'));
```

So you can get the values of the styled selects with `$("#selectbox1").val()` and `$("#selectbox2").val()`, just as if you were using normal selects.